# How can we use drawerLockMode in React Navigation v5.0

Tags: react-navigation

I am using react navigation v5.0 in my project.
In previous version there is an option called "drawerLockMode" by which we could disable swipe gesture from opening the navigation drawer in an specific screen.
How can I use this option in v5.0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `gestureEnabled` option

> Whether you can use gestures to open or close the drawer. Defaults to `true`.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-navigator.html#gestureenabled

Comment: thank you but how can i access drawer navigator's options from inside stack navigator? i have an stack navigator inside a drawer navigator so how can i access gestureEnabled within that stack navigator's pages?

Comment: i found it myself, inside inner stack navigator component we should use this code: 
`props.route.state.index > 0
    ? props.navigation.setOptions({ gestureEnabled: false })
    : peops.navigation.setOptions({ gestureEnabled: true })`, so only on the first screen of the inner stack navigator the drawer will be opened

Answer (score 0):

If using inside functional component, use React's useLayoutEffect() hook like this:

```html
function HomeStackNavigator({navigation, route}) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  //Lock drawer on all screens except the first one i.e. Home
  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {

    route.state !== undefined
      ? route.state.index > 0
        ? navigation.setOptions({gestureEnabled: false})
        : navigation.setOptions({gestureEnabled: true})
      : null;
  }, [navigation, route]);

  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home" headerMode="none">
     ...
    </Stack.Navigator>
```